# CORS prevent js window.onerror from subdomain reporting informations

Tags: nginx, http-headers, javascript, cors

To log Javascript errors i have set up a function with window.onerror which trigger an ajax request and inform me about script errors. I load all my static files from a subdomain and if an error occurs from a file outside of the main domain, CORS seem to delete informations because of leak...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#notes

I have tried to fix the problem by setting up Access-Control-Allow-Origin like that:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://static.example.com;
```

but with no success.

My subdomain carries aswell Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the main domain.

Header of the document:

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/de/kontaktformular.html
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: XXX
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin: https://static.example.com
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-encoding: br
content-security-policy: ...
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 10 Aug 2021 10:21:35 GMT
expect-ct: enforce,max-age=30
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
referrer-policy: same-origin
server: nginx
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
:authority: www.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /de/kontaktformular.html
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-IT,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-DE;q=0.6
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: __Host-PHPSESSID=k2284o6ejliq4t9113bicbv5tr; cookie_alert=1; cart=MjMtLC03OC0sLTF8fDU1LSwtMTI3LSwtMXx8NTUtLC0xMjgtLC0x
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://www.example.com/de/XXX.html
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
```

Header of the Js file which comes from subdomain:

```
Request URL: https://static.example.com/jquery_scripts.128.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: XXX
Referrer Policy: same-origin
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.example.com
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 10 Aug 2021 10:21:35 GMT
expires: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 10:21:35 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 10 Aug 2021 09:38:16 GMT
server: nginx
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
:authority: static.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /jquery_scripts.128.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-IT,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-DE;q=0.6
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: script
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: You have an additional unrelated problem: Your static file `/de/kontaktformular.html` is being served by PHP. This is probably an error in your nginx configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton   thanks for your input, the document is not static. I cant make the document static because i have dynamic content like login etc. Please tell me if i have mistaken your input and i can improve nginx configuration.

Comment: OK, if it is not actually a static file then there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the same documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#cors_and_caching):

> If the server sends a response with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value that is an explicit origin (rather than the "*" wildcard), then the response should also include a [Vary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary) response header with the value Origin — to indicate to browsers that server responses can differ based on the value of the Origin request header.
>
> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://developer.mozilla.org
> Vary: Origin
> ```

Comment: I have added Vary: Origin, but i wasnt able to replace with "vary: Accept-Encoding" header. So i have both headers "origin" and "accept-encoding". Unluckily its not working and i still dont recieve the error messages.

Comment: Ok i had to add `https://WWW.example.com` at my static files, not sure 100% why but its working now together with "vary".